# Why won't the audio play in safari

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a small JavaScript program that plays HappyBirthday using a setInterval to add 1 to a variable and depending on the value of the variable a certain note will play or pause.
My problem is that there is no audio playing when there should be.
Why won't the MP3 play in Safari which supports MP3?
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
<title>happy birthday</title>
<script>
function setNotes(){
a3=document.getElementById('n1')
a3s=document.getElementById('n2')
b3=document.getElementById('n3')
c4s=document.getElementById('n4')
d4s=document.getElementById('n5')
f4=document.getElementById('n6')
g3=document.getElementById('n7')
a4=document.getElementById('n9')
b4=document.getElementById('n10')
c5s=document.getElementById('n11')
d5s=document.getElementById('n12')
a5s=document.getElementById('n13')
c4=document.getElementById('n14') 
d4=document.getElementById('n15') 
e4=document.getElementById('n16') 
f5s=document.getElementById('n17') 
g5s=document.getElementById('n18') 
a4s=document.getElementById('n19') 
c5=document.getElementById('n20') 
d5=document.getElementById('n21') 
e5=document.getElementById('n22') 
g3.play();
g3.pause();
a3.play();
a3.pause()
c4.play()
c4.pause()
b3.play()
b3.pause()
d4.play()
d4.pause()
e4.play()
e4.pause()
f4.play()
f4.pause()

}
function start(){
setInterval(music, 150) 
}
tic=0;
function music(){
if (tic==1000){tic=0};
if (tic==0){g3.play();}
if (tic==3) {g3.pause();}
if (tic==4) {g3.play()}
if (tic==7) {g3.pause()}
if (tic==8) {a3.play()}
if (tic==11) {a3.pause()}
if (tic==12) {g3.play()}
if (tic==15) {g3.pause()}
if (tic==16) {c4.play()}
if (tic==19) {c4.pause()}
if (tic==20) {b3.play()}
if (tic==23) {b3.pause()} 
if (tic==26) {g3.play()}
if (tic==29) {g3.pause()}  
if (tic==30) {g3.play()} 
if (tic==33) {g3.pause()}
if (tic==34) {a3.play()} 
if (tic==37) {a3.pause()} 
if (tic==38) {g3.play()}  
if (tic==41) {g3.pause()} 
if (tic==42) {d4.play()} 
if (tic==45) {d4.pause()} 
if (tic==46) {c4.play()} 
if (tic==49) {c4.pause()}  
if (tic==52) {g3.play()}   
if (tic==55) {g3.pause()} 
if (tic==56) {g3.play()}   
if (tic==59) {g3.pause()} 
if (tic==60) {g3.play()}   
if (tic==63) {g3.pause()} 
if (tic==64) {e4.play()}
if (tic==67) {e4.pause()}
if (tic==68) {c4.play()} 
if (tic==71) {c4.pause()} 
if (tic==72) {b3.play()} 
if (tic==75) {b3.pause()} 
if (tic==76) {a3.play()} 
if (tic==79) {a3.pause()}  
if (tic==82) {f4.play() }
if (tic==85) {f4.pause() }
if (tic==86) {f4.play() } 
if (tic==89) {f4.pause() } 
if (tic==90) {e4.play()}
if (tic==93) {e4.pause()}
if (tic==94) {c4.play()}
if (tic==97) {c4.pause()}
if (tic==98) {d4.play()}
if (tic==101) {d4.pause()}
if (tic==102) {c4.play()}
if (tic==105) {c4.pause()}
++tic 
}
</script>
</head><body onload="setNotes();">
<button onclick="setTimeout(start, 3000)">play</button>
<audio id=n1 src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/A3-220.0.mp3"></audio>
<audio id=n2 src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Asharp3-233.08.mp3"></audio>
<audio id=n3 src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/B3-246.94.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="n4" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Csharp4-277.18.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n5" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Dsharp4-311.13.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n6" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/F4-349.23.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n7" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/G4-392.0.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n9" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/A4-440.0.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n10" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/B4-493.88.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n11" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Csharp5-554.37.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n12" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Dsharp5-622.25.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n13" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Asharp3-233.08.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n14" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/C4-261.63.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n15" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/D4-293.66.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n16" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/E4-329.63.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n17" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Fsharp4-369.99.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n18" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Gsharp4-415.3.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n19" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/Asharp4-466.16.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n20" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/C5-523.25.mp3"> </audio>
<audio id="n21" src="http://jetcityorange.com/musical-notes/D5-587.33.mp3"> </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show only the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce your problem; I don't believe that *all* of those elements are necessary; please take a read of the "*[mcve]*," and "*[ask]*," guidelines.

Comment: As it is thats a template i made for this and future use when i can ill edit it and repost if I don't get an answer here

Answer (score 0):

try with .ogg. Some formats of music files don't work on certain browsers.